# Function pointer iterator in Berkeley DB

Tags: c, iterator, function-pointers, berkeley-db

I'm implementing an iterator to go over the records from a Berkeley DB. However, it seems I need to set the `DB_DBT_USERMEM` flag before the call to cursor->get with DB_NEXT.

Doing it that way would make my iterator less cohesive and will have to implement multiple iterators for each data type I want to retrieve.

Is there a way to have a generic iterator that can traverse structures w/o pointers, and basic data types?  Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <db.h>

// let this function handle integers and use DB_DBT_USERMEM for memory alignment
void integer_items(DBT key, DBT data) {
        int number = 0;
        data.data = &number;
        data.flags = DB_DBT_USERMEM;
        data.ulen = sizeof(int);
        printf("key is: %s, data is: %d\n", (char *) key.data,number);
}

// let this function handle pointer structs. No need for DB_DBT_USERMEM
void ptr_struct_items(DBT key, DBT data) {
        // MY_STRUCT user;
        // marshall struct...
        // buffsize = sizeof(int) +(strlen(user.familiar_name) + strlen(user.surname) + 2);
        // databuff = malloc(buffsize);
        // memset(databuff, 0, buffsize);  
        // ...
        // printf("key is: %s, data is: %d\n", (char *) key.data,number);
}

int iterator(DB *database, void(*function)(DBT key, DBT data)) {
        DBT key, data;
        DBC *cursor;

        memset(&key, 0, sizeof(DBT));
        memset(&data, 0, sizeof(DBT));
        database->cursor(database, NULL, &cursor, 0);
        while(cursor->c_get(cursor, &key, &data, DB_NEXT) == 0){
                (*function)(key, data);
        }
        cursor->c_close(cursor);
        return 0;
}

int main() {
        DB_ENV *myEnv;
        DB *dbp;
        DBT key, data;
        int r, v = 10;
        char *k = "Test";

        db_env_create(&myEnv, 0);
        myEnv->open(myEnv, "./", DB_CREATE | DB_INIT_MPOOL, 0);

        db_create(&dbp, myEnv, 0);
        dbp->open(dbp, NULL, "test.db", NULL, DB_HASH, DB_CREATE, 0664);

        memset(&key, 0, sizeof(key));
        memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));

        key.data = k;
        key.size = strlen(k) +1;
        data.data = &v;
        data.size = sizeof(int);

        if((r=dbp->put(dbp, NULL, &key, &data, 0)!=0))
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", db_strerror(r));

        iterator(dbp, integer_items);
        iterator(dbp, ptr_struct_items);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost always want to use DB_DBT_USERMEM, if only to avoiding the malloc() from inside BDB for DB_DBT_MALLOC/REALLOC.  When you use it, you must pass in your own memory large enough to hold the largest item in your database.  This holds for the key DBT too, as you may want to use it there.

In your example, as the key and data are so small, I'd just put character arrays on the stack in your "iterator" function, and then initialize key and data after the call to memset().  What you've got above is wrong because you're setting USERMEM after the call to c_get().

Here's a reworked example that gives BDB 256 bytes to work with for key and data.

```
void integer_items(DBT key, DBT data) {
        int number = 0;

        if (data.size == sizeof number) {
            number = *(int *)data.data;
            printf("key is: %s, data is: %d\n", (char *) key.data, number);
        }
}

int iterator(DB *database, void(*function)(DBT key, DBT data)) {
        DBT key, data;
        DBC *cursor;
        char kmem[256];
        char dmem[256];

        memset(&key, 0, sizeof(DBT));
        memset(&data, 0, sizeof(DBT));

        key.flags  = DB_DBT_USERMEM;
        key.data   = kmem;
        key.ulen   = sizeof kmem;

        data.flags = DB_DBT_USERMEM;
        data.data  = dmem;
        data.ulen  = sizeof dmem;

        database->cursor(database, NULL, &cursor, 0);
        while(cursor->c_get(cursor, &key, &data, DB_NEXT) == 0){
                (*function)(key, data);
        }
        cursor->c_close(cursor);
        return 0;
}
```

To handle different structures inside your iterator, include the data type as part of the key somehow. For example, instead of a bare integer for the key, use a struct, and have the first character define which kind of type it is. Then, inside your iterator function, you can switch on that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a way that the iterator can traverse structures w/o pointers, and basic types and let the pointed-to function handle the type? as opposed to multiple iterators for each data type. I have updated the example.

Comment: The typical way of handling that is to include the data type as part of the key somehow.  For example, instead of a bare integer for the key, use a struct, and have the first character define which kind of type it is.  Then, inside your iterator function, you can switch on that.

Comment: Thanks, that appears to be what I'm looking for.